# Salesforce 1 Community Cloud - Chatter Community Rebranding?

Tags: community

Salesforce [announced](http://www.salesforce.com/company/news-press/press-releases/2014/08/140827.jsp) the new "Salesforce 1 Community Cloud" some days ago. On the other hand the [information](http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/features/communities.jsp) about "Chatter Communities" seems to be outdated.

Therefore my questions are:

1. **Is the new "Salesforce 1 Community Cloud" the same as "[Salesforce Communities](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEzegnVNoRc)"?**
2. **Is Chatter (and / or Chatter +) part of "Salesforce 1 Community Cloud"?**
3. And is "[company community](http://www.salesforce.com/company/news-press/press-releases/2013/05/130530.jsp)" the same as "employee community"?

Regarding my second question: I think it's possible that Chatter or Chatter Plus could be part of Salesforce 1 Community Cloud because it could fit well in the product matrix...

[image: Product Matrix]

(Product matrix is based on the information from the following sites: http://www.salesforce.com/sales-cloud/overview/ http://www.salesforce.com/service-cloud/overview/ http://www.salesforce.com/communities/overview/ http://www.salesforce.com/platform/overview/

Comment: I think SF is confusing everyone in general with their use of Salesforce 1 branding. My understanding of the primary feature that was to be "new" is that SF1 VF page capabilities would now be enabled for use in communities. Most of what went beyond that was enabling access to mobile feature enhancements they've been testing which customers have requested. It appears to me as though its more of SF's Marketing Dept once again making it difficult to differentiate between their product licenses as they continue to rebrand their products.

Comment: Agreed that marketing is making things overly confusing. Yes, Salesforce 1 Community Cloud is the same thing as Salesforce Communities.  They just couldn't have a product without the word "cloud" in it. :) I like how you put Chatter Plus as part of the Community Cloud. Not sure if Salesforce would agree, but it seems to make sense to me as it is the "basic" version of Community Cloud. Just FYI Marketing Cloud includes Radian6, BuddyMedia, and Exact Target but not in a hierarchy order.